# How was Commander Cody's full body being projected on Darth Sidious' office table when there was no camera?

Tags: star-wars, technology, revenge-of-the-sith

This might come across as foolish question, but how was Commander Cody's full body being projected to Sidious and vice versa when neither of the two had space age film crews or intergalactic iPhones filming themselves?

I imagine hand held holo projectors have a way of doing a full body scan of individuals but I have found no conclusive evidence yet to suggest

[image: commander cody receives order 66]

Comment: What do you know about futuristic communicators?

Comment: I'm not sure you can assume that Star Wars holoprojectors have the same limitations as current-day cameras. They are capable of 3-dimensional projection and recording -- it may not require a direct line-of-sight to the rear of an object in order to scan and project it.

Comment: I wonder this all the time in Star Wars

Comment: @MikasaPinata - So you're ok with the Emperor using an all-encompassing magical force to take over the galaxy but a modest improvement in present-day video technology breaks the fourth wall for you?

Comment: @Valorum Pardon? I never said it broke the 4th wall. It's exactly the opposite of that; I'm wondering how the technology works. There are times in the movies where it's unclear as to where the scanning technology is, so it's a valid question. The Clone Wars TV show is certainly much better at clarifying it than the movies are.

Answer (score 9):

It's fairly clear that "holo-scanners" in the Star Wars universe are able to view and record an object in multiple dimensions. They aren't looking *through* the subject but act as if they're observing the exterior from multiple angles, even those that should be blocked from view.

We see this in the original Star Wars film when R2-D2 scans Princess Leia for the famous "Help me Obi-Wan" speech. Clearly it's filmed from a single perspective, yet R2D2 is capable of producing a 3-dimensional representation of Leia for later playback.

[image] [image]

Comment: Apparently the holo-scanner is also able to put Leia's hood up over her head as well.

Comment: @Oldcat - She's pressing the "fire Continuity Supervisor" button

Answer (score 1):

It is likely Sidious' office has discreet hidden cameras for exactly this purpose.

We don't know exactly what equipment Cody has in the field, but it's reasonable to suppose one of the other clone troopers is operating a portable communications rig of some kind, which is equipped with a camera.

**Edit:** As commenters pointed out, the view from behind is clearly "live" and not a stored image. So there must be multiple cameras positioned around the subject. For a pre-installed system such as the one in Sidious' office this would be simple enough. A portable communication device might have to deploy little flying camera-drones to do the job.

Comment: There's no evidence to suggest that the rear view is a stored image.

Comment: No, rear image isn't stored image. In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV series, we have seen live actions in communicator holograms. For example, in the first episode of the TV series, you can see Yoda killing a droid in hologram..

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, the only explanation is multiple cameras positioned around the subject. It's obvious how this would work in Sidious' office, less so for a field communications rig. Maybe the latter deploys little flying camera-drones, or something.

Comment: Why do there have to be multiple cameras?  It would be a simple matter for a computer to interpolate and add in missing imagery (i.e. his backside) based on a single camera's input.  We have tech that can do a basic version of that today.

Comment: Clearly these holograms result from some type of scanner than scans your entire body or an envelope of space around you. Of course this scanner can be located anywhere. It's very unlikely that they're using mundane cameras.

Comment: @BBlake: That's sort of what I was getting at. Making it work for showing combat (instead of a person just standing there talking) would be much harder but not impossible.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: All-seeing hyperspace scanners would certainly do the trick, but if you're willing to posit "magical" technology, then it sort of takes the fun out of answering these questions.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit Not really. It was clearly not done with mundane cameras, from any angle possible in the "field" you'd imagine a wrist mounted camera would have the best view of the speaker, but this view would still be limited to the head at best. Trying to describe this with simple cameras is like trying to describe how email works using pulleys and levers as its building blocks.